# How Route 53 Geo DNS works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I have setup 2 Geodns A record of example.com:

- Europe = example.com (`192.0.2.1`)
- India = example.com (`192.0.2.2`)

and it gave me 4 ns record `ns[1-4].aws.amazon.com`

I understand if I `nslookup` from India

```
nslookup example.com ns[1-4].aws.amazon.com
```

gives `192.0.2.2`

but what I don't understand how `nslookup` from india with Google DNS `8.8.8.8`

```
nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8
```

gives `192.0.2.2`

Does `8.8.8.8` knows both A record of `example.com` and return the request based on location?

Comment: You should prefer `dig` over `nslookup` for better debugging (and also note to add to @faermanj reply that `dig` allows you to send ECS options by hand, to try things), and also remember that Google is not the only one entity providing large public DNS resolvers... You have as well `1.1.1.1`, `9.9.9.9`, `80.80.80.80`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The DNS server (`8.8.8.8`) does a lookup of the nameservers associated with the domain (`ns[1-4].aws.amazon.com`). It then forwards the request to one of those nameservers.

So, `8.8.8.8` is not doing the geo-lookup. Rather, the AWS nameserver is doing the geo-lookup. It looks at the IP address of the original request and returns either `192.0.2.1` or `192.0.2.2` as appropriate.

Even without specifying `8.8.8.8`, your DNS request is being forwarded to a DNS service in your organization or in your ISP, and the same thing happens.

If you wish to test whether the `192.0.2.1` lookup is working, you will need to do it from an IP address that is located closer to Europe than to India.

Answer (score 1):

That is likely because the resolution is not based on the nameserver address, but the client address. The nameserver uses the [EDNS Client Subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDNS_Client_Subnet) extension to fetch the client subnet address and try to infer an aproximation of geolocation. It is similar latency based routing: it would not make sense to consider the nameserver address as that is nearly constant, while clients can vary a lot.

Comment: And/Or since Google Public DNS is anycasted as well, the instance that replies to queries for this case is close (topologically wise) to the requestor, which means that the authoritative nameservers will reply with the same data.